# C# IF part works as it should, however, ELSE part is always executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, if-statement

I must admit I am new to C# MVC 4 programming, but I've never seen such a weird thing in any other programming language...

The if part inside the foreach works good, however, even if it's true, the else part gets executed, which is very strange.

When I remove " @dag.Datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ", the if else works, but unfortunately that is not what I want.

Thanks in advance for any help!

(ow and sorry for the dutch I used in my code)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <br /><br /><table>
    @foreach (var cursist in Model.Cursisten.Where(cursist => cursist.Soort == 1))
    {
        <tr>

            <th>@cursist.Email</th>

            @foreach (var dag in Model.Opleidingsdagen.Where(m => m.chked == true))
            {
                <td>

                    @foreach (var afw in Model.Afwezigheden)
                    {
                        if (afw.DagID.Equals(dag.DagID) && afw.CursistID.Equals(cursist.Email))
                        {
                            @:a @dag.Datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @:b
                        } 
                    }

                </td>
            }


        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="Afwezigheden aanpassen" class="btn" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
```

EDIT
    and this is the html table output I always get:

```
testacc1@test.be     a 14/08/2013 b  b a 15/08/2013  b b
testacc2@test.be     b b     b b     b b
testacc3@test.be     b b     b b     b b
```

EDIT #2
my expected output is:

```
testacc1@test.be     a 14/08/2013    a 15/08/2013 b
testacc2@test.be     b               b            b
testacc3@test.be     b               b            b
```

so there always is a 'b', even when an 'a + date ' is outputted

Comment: Is `@:a ` and `@:b ` really part of your syntax?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a single razor file without any external dependencies, so that others can easily test it as well?

Comment: perhaps I'm confused but: I see 6 elements in each row; in row 1, two of them are 'a (date)' elements instead of 'b' elements. What did you *expect* it to output?

Comment: The output looks fine to me. It's doing exactly what the algorithm says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bug and it is working fine. You have 3 nested foreach loops, which produce 6 outputs per email address and 2 within each `<td>`, put a breakpoint in the code and follow the logic. I am 100% sure this is a bug on your end not MS.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try:

`<text>a @dag.Datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</text>`

in the if statement?

It's possible that the Razor parser is getting a bit confused and executing the `else` clause because of the format of the `@:a @dag.Datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` line.

EDIT:

What happens if you try

```
@foreach (var afw in Model.Afwezigheden)
{
    if (true)
    {
        @:a @dag.Datum.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    }
    else
    {
        @:b
    } 
}
```

Is the `else` clause also executed?

EDIT:

Ahh OK, based on your comment, then it does seem that your `if` statement clause is returning `false`, otherwise I cannot see how the `else` clause can ever be executed. Extract each part into a variable:

```
bool idMatch = afw.DagID.Equals(dag.DagID);
bool emailMatch = afw.CursistID.Equals(cursist.Email);

if (idMatch && emailMatch)
```

It will be easier to determine which equality if failing.

Comment: @Bram, are you saying the `if` **and** the `else` get executed on *every single iteration*